# Update item in a SharePoint list from another SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, date-time, power-automate

I have two SharePoint lists: List A and List B.

Both lists have a column with a special number called VHE (text column) and a column Date.

The Date column in List B is still empty and I would like to fill it with the values of the Date column in list A, if the VHE numbers in both lists match.

I started a flow in which I 'Get items' from both lists.
And then added a condition that If VHE number in list A is equal to VHE number in list B, the Date Column from List B is updated.

But that does not work. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing any error after flow runs? Both columns have same data type (text) in both lists?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, I cannot reproduce your problem. Are there any error messages when you are testing and running the flow?

**My Test:**

1.I have two lists in the same site.

- ListA: Testb

[image]

- ListB: Copy_Testb

[image]

2.Create Microsoft Flow

[image]

3.Save and Test this Flow

It is worth noting that since you choose "**Manually trigger a flow**" Trigger, you need to trigger the flow manually.

[image]

[image]

========================== **Updated Answer** =========================

According to my research, because there are more than 5,000 items in your list. Therefore, I suggest that you can set **Filter Query** in **"Get items"** action to make the number of obtained items less than the threshold of 5,000.

**Reference:**

- [Filtering Power Automate (Flow) “Get Items” with Filter Query](https://ppmworks.com/filtering-flow-get-items-with-filter-query/)
- [OData Filter query in SharePoint Get items in Power Automate](https://sharepains.com/2018/11/12/sharepoint-get-items-odata-filter-query/)

Comment: Hi I tried this, but i get a Time-out error when running the flow. List B has over over 7.000 items.

Comment: Hi Mirjam Kaal. Regardless of the Power Automate license, the "Get Items" Action limitation is 5000 items. This is a limit of the SharePoint REST API, and not Power Automate. Reference: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/What-is-the-maximum-limit-for-Get-Items-action-in-MS-flow-for/td-p/136275

Comment: Aha, but is there another way to get the same result?

Comment: Hi Mirjam Kaal. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: so far, the flow is succesfull. However the items are not changed. So i am doing something wrong. I will try again this afternoon.

Comment: Hi Mirjam Kaal. Would you tell me whether your issue has been resolved or have any update?